# dropdown menu in Reactjs and Sass

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I designed a drop-down menu with keyframes and reactjs.
this menu is what I want [enter link description here](http://demo.templatemonster.com/demo/104257.html?_gl=1*nxafp9*_ga*MTEyMDc0MzQ0MC4xNjY4NjcwNjMy*_ga_FTPYEGT5LY*MTY2ODY3MDYzMi4xLjAuMTY2ODY3MDYzMy41OS4wLjA.&_ga=2.32684406.979180427.1668670633-1120743440.1668670632)

but I do not know how to apply a drop-up animation when an item menu is open and client click to another item menu. in my code it gets disappear suddenly without any animtion.
this is my code:
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hypatia-qvlnhq?file=/src/styles.scss)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this behavior is that your `ul` element after open of another element, lose all classes except `collapse`, to achieve your expected behavior, you need to modify your conditions for class add like that:

```
<ul
  className={`collapse ${
  openedMenu === "menu" && open
    ? "show"
    : "hidden"
  }`}
>
```

Paste this condition to all places and try it out. [Here is link to updated codesandbox with working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-worker-yessdk?file=/src/App.js)